# How do you pattern-match against negative 1?

Tags: ats

This fails with "`the pattern is expected to be formed with a constructor (of datavtype)`", as it's matching the special free()ing syntax for linear constructors rather than the negative sign.

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
implement main0() =
        case ~1 of
        | ~1 => println!("ok")
        | _ => ()
```

---

This fails with "`operator fixity cannot be resolved`". It doesn't help to add parens or to make a binary operator.

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
implement main0() =
        case ~1 of
        | -1 => println!("ok")
        | _ => ()
```

---

This fails as the variable in the `case` introduces a new binding, unrelated to the binding already in scope:

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
implement main0() =
        let
                val negative_one = ~1
        in
                case ~2 of
                | negative_one => println!("unintend match")
                | _ => () // error: this pattern match clause is redundant
        end
```

---

Is this the closest we can get? How much less performant is it?

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
implement main0() =
        let
                val negative_one = ~1
        in
                ifcase
                | negative_one = ~1 => println!("this works")
                | _ => ()
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ATS, ~1 is not considered a constant; it is a function application: ~ being applied to 1. You can define negative 1 as follows:

```
#define NEG1 %(~1) // not yet working // to be fixed
```

or

```
#define NEG1 %(0-1) // this one is currently working
```

Then you can write:

```
case ~1 of
| 1 => ...
| NEG1 => ...
```

Using 'ifcase' (instead of 'case') should be equally efficient.